# How to create dynamic video/slideshow from pictures in PHP

Tags: php, xml-swf-charts

I have a dynamic archive (a folder on my ftp space) where are loaded images from webcam. Now i want to create an easy slideshow or video with these images each time the user want to  watch it.
No any transition options or others....i need to build a siple timelapse from images captured by camera.

i've just try this http://www.maani.us/xml_slideshow/ it works fine (i can build with php a dynamic xml configuration file for the swf script) but i can't set the time transition less than 1 second...and is not free...

Any simple solution? (also javascript if it is better...)
Thanx!

Comment: Try searching for the term "jpeg to mpeg converter" then append "PHP" to the term too.

Comment: Some slideshow with effect in below link https://github.com/letungit90/ffmpeg_memo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the best way i found: simple and speedy

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Video</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY  BGCOLOR="#000000">
<img name="foto">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var Pic = new Array();

Pic[0] = '/images/image1.jpg'
Pic[1] = '/images/image2.jpg'
Pic[2] = '/images/image3.jpg'
//this part in real code is replaced with a PHP script that print image location dinamically

var t;
var j = 0;
var p = Pic.length;
var preLoad = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
preLoad[i] = new Image();
preLoad[i].src = Pic[i];
}
//all images are loaded on client
index = 0;
function update(){
if (preLoad[index]!= null){
document.images['foto'].src = preLoad[index].src;
index++;
setTimeout(update, 1000);
}

}
update();

</script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the end result to be a video file you could do something similar to what I did when turning a series of Google Streetview panoramas into an [immersive time-lapse video](http://www.flickr.com/photos/swilsonmc/4043758825/in/set-72157605886667055/).

It's all done on the server using PHP & ffmpeg.  Here's some sample code pared down from the [original source](http://pastebin.com/t38h0y90).

ffmpeg command:

```
$makeMovieFfmpeg = "ffmpeg -r 4 -f image2 -i dir/%d.jpg -s 800x600 -r 15 -s 800x600 -b 1500kbs myvideo.avi 2>&1";
```

Explanation:

```
-r 4 //input framerate of 4fps
-f image2 //invoke the image2 file demuxer since we're working with a series of images
-i //location of image files with applied pattern where %d represents numeric sequence
-s //input image size
-r //output framerate of 15fps
-s //output video size
-b //set the bitrate
2>&1 //redirects stderr to stdout in order to make output available to PHP
```

Execute command:

```
print_r (exec($makeMovieFfmpeg,$ret,$err));
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a merely string manipulation language

You cannot create a slideshow in PHP. It's server-side language.

Comment: Write sensible title / tags please.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can create GIF sequence like one in here:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/53942-create-gif-images-using-gd/

Answer (score 0):

Ffmpeg is your best solution. https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Fast way to create slideshow from image is running below command

```
ffmpeg -framerate 20 \
-loop 1 -t 0.5 -i 1.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 0.5 -i 2.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 0.5 -i 3.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 0.5 -i 4.jpg \
-c:v libx264 \
-filter_complex " \
[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v]; \
[2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b2v]; \
[3:v][2:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b3v]; \
[0:v][b1v][1:v][b2v][2:v][b3v][3:v]concat=n=7:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4
```

it will create a slideshow with blend effect.

You can check below memo for other effect https://github.com/letungit90/ffmpeg_memo