# How to make a server side slideshow

Tags: php, javascript, slideshow, server-side

I am trying to find the best way to go about making a server-side slide-show, where the program will get pictures from a folder called /inviteuploads, and display the contents of that folder in the slideshow (the folder will only contain images). I would be happy to use Javascript, HTML, PHP, or anything else you suggest. Maybe this isn't even possible, but please let me know! 
Also i saw this post: [How to create dynamic video/slideshow from pictures in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546302/how-to-create-dynamic-video-slideshow-from-pictures-in-php) 
But that didn't really answer my question, i need to get the uploads from the folder and have them displayed in the slideshow. Also, i dont *only* want to use php, i am open to any other suggested languages.
Thanks!

Comment: Slideshow is an visual element that user sees in his browser. That is the client side. You can process images on the server side like crop them or whatever, you can save them, download from another server, handle uploads or get paths/urls to them but you cannot display the images on the server side of the app.

Comment: Well, you're going to need to make some decisions:  How is data flow going to work?  Are you going to return an HTML page with img tags for all the slides, Or use AJAX to get the next slide just in time?  If you're displaying this in a browser, then HTML is chosen for you, but maybe you want to separate out your webserver and your services layer?  These design considerations require a pretty intimate knowledge of the product, and we can't get that from a one paragraph  question.  You may want to find someone in person you can bat this around with.  There's a lot of give and take in design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is in asp.net...jquery library is required for animation

I am using pagemethods property of scriptmanager to access images present in folder "inviteuploads" and then displaying them in a div container...return value will contain location of the images seperated by "\u000d"...i am using fadin and fadeout effects..you can use any effects of your choice :)

see the code below:

**Server Side Code**

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod, System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string slideshow()
{
    string filename = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("inviteuploads"));

        for (int i = 0; i < Files.Length; i++)
        {
            filename += "inviteupload/" + Path.GetFileName(Files[i]) + "\u000d";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return filename;
}
```

**Client Side Code**

```
 function slideshow() {

        PageMethods.slideshow(successslideshow, failureslideshow);

        function successslideshow(msg) {
            var arr = msg.split("\u000d");
            var i = 0;

            for (j = 0; j < (arr.length - 1); j++) {
                $("#divslideshow").append("<img id=imgslideshow_" + j + " src=" + arr[j] + " width=700px height=700px style='display:none; max-height: 700px; max-width: 700px;' />");
            }

            $("#imgslideshow_" + i).fadeIn();
            setInterval(function () {
                $("#imgslideshow_" + i).fadeOut(function () {
                    i++;
                    if (i <= (arr.length - 2)) {
                        $("#imgslideshow_" + i).fadeIn();
                    }
                    else {
                        i = 0;
                        $("#imgslideshow_" + i).fadeIn();
                    }
                });
            }, 6000);
        }

        function failureslideshow(msg) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: hmmm so this would require the page to be .asp instead of .php? or could i execute this on a php page? The only reason i ask is because i have something on the same page that uses php. Thanks!

Comment: Also i have no experience whatsoever with asp, so how would i include this in a php page, or a html page?

Comment: or you can use glob function as told by @Ahmmad...but if you want to do the same in asp.net you can use this code...

Comment: does this require the page extension to be .asp? or can it execute on a .php page

Comment: yes extension will be .aspx....you can find a working demo on this link [oncloudcrm](http://www.oncloudcrm.com)...

Answer (score 2):

use glob function.

see: [Listing all images in a directory using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738270/listing-all-images-in-a-directory-using-php)

now use the image path to make the slideshow.

Comment: thanks! I already have a program that lists all the files in a folder, so i can just copy the code from that. If i run into a problem i will let you know in another comment. Thanks again!